# How to add multiple Objects to an empty array react after getting response from Api react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am uploding 4 images in response i am getting 4 urls one by one save 4 urls in 4 diffrent objects

```
const [multiStatement, setMultiStatement] = useState([])

const multipStatement = async(e) => {
  const files = e.target.files 
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {          
    const url = await uploadStaement(files[i])
    console.log(url)
    setMultiStatement([...multiStatement, {type:"document", frontBack:"front", url:url}])
  }
}
<input type="file" id="file" multiple name="file" onChange={multipStatement} />
```

Comment: What is the current output when you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time through the loop you are overwriting the work you did before. If `multiStatement` was an empty array when this started, then you first set the state to empty array + object with url 0, then empty array + object with url 1, and so on. At the end, the only one that sticks is empty array + object with the last url.

To fix this, use the function version of setMultiStatement, so you are always working with the latest state:

```
setMultiStatement(prev => [...prev, {type:"document", frontBack:"front", url:url}]);
```